# Importing LESS as a reference then later importing the same file without reference

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

If you use `@import(reference)` in LESS and then subsequently import the same LESS file without using (reference) the subsequent import is ignored.

e.g.

*Stylesheet1:*

```
#In1 { background-color: red; }
```

*Stylesheet2:*

```
@import (reference) 'Stylesheet1.less';
#In2 { background-color: blue; #In1; }
```

*Stylesheet3:*

```
@import 'Stylesheet2.less';
@import 'Stylesheet1.less';
#In3 { background-color: green; }
```

So Stylesheet2 imports stylesheet1 but instructs LESS not to output the styles from the imported file unless they are used (as per the #In1; mixin)

Stylesheet3 then imports Stylesheet2, not knowing that it already imports Stylesheet1.
It then imports Stylesheet1 without the (reference) directive, with the intention of directly outputting the styles.

*Expected output:*

```
#In2 { background-color: blue; background-color: red; }
#In1 { background-color: red;}
#In3 { background-color: green;}
```

*Actual output:*

```
#In2 { background-color: blue; background-color: red; }
#In3 { background-color: green;}
```

Am I missing an option on the import statement to make this work or this is a bug in LESS (or web-essentials2012s' implementation of LESS).

Having found the cause of this I can easily enough swap the imports statements in Stylesheet3 around and the issue go away however I'd prefer to have a solution that doesn't require knowing the contents of the imported LESS file.

Comment: `@import` implies [`once`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-once) option so if you want `#In1` to appear you need to use `multiple` for the corresponding import.

Comment: but that requires knowing that Stylehseet2 already imported Stylesheet1 as reference.
I would expect the later import without the reference directive to effectively override the earlier reference-only import

Comment: >but that requires knowing that Stylehseet2 already imported Stylesheet1 as reference - Yes. (I just indicated how it works not how consistent or inconsistent it is. And yes, I agree it would make sense to not count `reference` imports for `once`).